# Apache Ignite on YARN not working - node container logs not present

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, ignite

We 've been trying to get Apache Ignite(2.1.0) to run on YARN(running on HDP 2.6) following this guide: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/yarn-deployment
(we are running in an offline environment)

Although we get the application to start, `stderr` logs from YARN AM container are the only ones we can see(`stdout` is empty) and they look like this:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/disk/09/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hongmei/appcache/application_1464374946035_32224/filecache/10/ignite-yarn.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/06/10 08:43:48 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: yarn.client.max-cached-nodemanagers-proxies : 0
16/06/10 08:43:48 INFO client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider: Failing over to rm2
Jun 10, 2016 8:43:48 AM org.apache.ignite.yarn.ApplicationMaster run
INFO: Application master registered.
Jun 10, 2016 8:43:48 AM org.apache.ignite.yarn.ApplicationMaster run
INFO: Making request. Memory: 2,432, cpu 1.
Jun 10, 2016 8:43:48 AM org.apache.ignite.yarn.ApplicationMaster run
INFO: Making request. Memory: 2,432, cpu 1.
16/06/10 08:43:49 INFO impl.AMRMClientImpl: Received new token for : c5hdp105.c5.runwaynine.com:45454
16/06/10 08:43:49 INFO impl.AMRMClientImpl: Received new token for : c5hdp112.c5.runwaynine.com:45454
Jun 10, 2016 8:43:49 AM org.apache.ignite.yarn.ApplicationMaster run
INFO: Making request. Memory: 2,432, cpu 1.
Jun 10, 2016 8:43:49 AM org.apache.ignite.yarn.ApplicationMaster run
INFO: Making request. Memory: 2,432, cpu 1.
Jun 10, 2016 8:43:49 AM org.apache.ignite.yarn.ApplicationMaster onContainersAllocated
INFO: Launching container: container_e24_1464374946035_32224_01_000002.
16/06/10 08:43:49 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: Opening proxy : c5hdp105.c5.runwaynine.com:45454
Jun 10, 2016 8:43:49 AM org.apache.ignite.yarn.ApplicationMaster onContainersAllocated
INFO: Launching container: container_e24_1464374946035_32224_01_000003.
16/06/10 08:43:49 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: Opening proxy : c5hdp112.c5.runwaynine.com:45454
16/06/10 08:43:50 INFO impl.AMRMClientImpl: Received new token for : c5hdp114.c5.runwaynine.com:45454
16/06/10 08:43:50 INFO impl.AMRMClientImpl: Received new token for : c5hdp115.c5.runwaynine.com:45454
Jun 10, 2016 8:43:50 AM org.apache.ignite.yarn.ApplicationMaster onContainersCompleted
INFO: Container completed. Container id: container_e24_1464374946035_32224_01_000006. State: COMPLETE.
Jun 10, 2016 8:43:50 AM org.apache.ignite.yarn.ApplicationMaster onContainersCompleted
INFO: Container completed. Container id: container_e24_1464374946035_32224_01_000007. State: COMPLETE.
Jun 10, 2016 8:43:50 AM org.apache.ignite.yarn.ApplicationMaster onContainersCompleted
INFO: Container completed. Container id: container_e24_1464374946035_32224_01_000004. State: COMPLETE.
Jun 10, 2016 8:43:50 AM org.apache.ignite.yarn.ApplicationMaster onContainersCompleted
INFO: Container completed. Container id: container_e24_1464374946035_32224_01_000005. State: COMPLETE.
```

The above log keeps going on forever(>1 day) and essentially what happens is that YARN keeps launching/killing containers to always match the number of `IGNITE_NODE_COUNT` we have provided in the Ignite conf file. I can also confirm that by viewing the `rm-audit.log` which has **TONS** of sequenced operations like this:

```
..
..
OPERATION=AM Allocated Container .... RESULT=SUCCESS <containerid1>
OPERATION=AM Allocated Container .... RESULT=SUCCESS <containerid2>
OPERATION=AM Allocated Container .... RESULT=SUCCESS <containerid3>
OPERATION=AM Released Container .... RESULT=SUCCESS <containerid1>
OPERATION=AM Released Container .... RESULT=SUCCESS <containerid2>
OPERATION=AM Released Container .... RESULT=SUCCESS <containerid3>
..
..
```

When I try to access the logs of each of the containers YARN doesn't show me those with the message that `Logs for container <container_id> are not present in this log-file`. I have tried seeing those with YARN UI and with `yarn logs -applicationId <application_id> -containerId <contaienrId>` .

I have tried with both `yarn.log-aggregation-enable` property set to `true` and `false` but logs are not getting generated even in the local filesystem. All the logs I get are from the AM container keep repeating the same message like shown above.

How can I enable the logs for each other container? Without those I cannot tell what's wrong in my Ignite setup. Please help.

**cluster.properties** file(Ignite)

```
IGNITE_NODE_COUNT=3
IGNITE_RUN_CPU_PER_NODE=2
IGNITE_MEMORY_PER_NODE=1024
IGNITE_XML_CONFIG=/data/ignite/<xml_name>.xml
IGNITE_WORK_DIR=/data/ignite/work
IGNITE_RELEASES_DIR=/data/ignite/releases
IGNITE_VERSION=2.1.0
IGNITE_PATH=/data/ignite/<path_to_ignite>.zip
```

Comment: Could you share your cluster.properties file?

Comment: updated answer with cluster.properties file

Comment: @NikolayTikhonov I should mention that my stderr/stdout for the AM container are as described in this JIRA ticket which is still open. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2927

Comment: This was due to a misconfiguration of the networking between the cluster hosts and the XML config